# ValueError: Disallowed subobject type: Topic for Products.PressRoom Plone 4.3

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I installed Products.PressRoom 3.3 on a Plone 4.3.7 instance. When i try to create a Press room at site root, i get `ValueError: Disallowed subobject type: Topic`

```
Traceback (innermost last):
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPythonScript, line 105, in __call__
Module Products.CMFFormController.Script, line 145, in __call__
Module Products.CMFCore.FSPythonScript, line 127, in __call__
Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
Module script, line 35, in createObject
- <FSControllerPythonScript at /le-temps-pour-toit-one/createObject>
- Line 35
Module Products.CMFCore.PortalFolder, line 292, in invokeFactory
Module Products.CMFCore.TypesTool, line 833, in constructContent
Module Products.CMFCore.TypesTool, line 311, in constructInstance
Module Products.CMFCore.TypesTool, line 552, in _constructInstance
Module Products.PressRoom.content.PressRoom, line 7, in addPressRoom
Module Products.PressRoom.content.PressRoom, line 135, in initializeArchetype
Module Products.PressRoom.content.PressRoom, line 166, in _createSubFolders
Module Products.ATContentTypes.lib.constraintypes, line 280, in invokeFactory
ValueError: Disallowed subobject type: Topic
```

Can anyone help me to solve this ?

Thank you

Comment: When i tick  Implicitly addable in portal_types/Topic, it works fine. Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Topic` content type has been deprecated starting from Plone 4.2.

So you can:

1. Enable old style collections (as you did), and the way to go is exactly to ticking it as globally addable. But in this way you'll have *two* kind of collection in the site
2. Fix PressRoom package to use `Collection` instead of `Topic`. If you are lucky, it will simply "just works". Think about opening as issue into the [project issue tracker](https://github.com/collective/Products.PressRoom/issues) also